# Align Checkbox in asp:TreeView

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have in my asp.net page asp:TreeView which generates checkboxes in codebehind.

```
<asp:TreeView  ID="TreeView1" Width="250px" NodeWrap="true" 
 ExpandDepth="1 ShowCheckBoxes="All" runat="server">
</asp:TreeView>
```

In the code behind elements and child elements are generated in this fashion inside a resultset loop.

```
 TreeNode tn1 = new TreeNode();

 TreeNode tn2 = new TreeNode();
 tn2.Text = "Child1";
 tn2.Value = "Child2";
 tn1.ChildNodes.Add(tn2);
```

However in the page the checkboxes are not aligned properly. I want to align them horizontally left.
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a css class and now whitespaces are removed before the checkboxes and horizontal alignment is working properly.

```
.tv table tbody tr 
{  
    display: inline-block;  
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left :5px;
    width: 100%;  
}

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" CssClass="tv" NodeIndent="2" NodeWrap="true" ExpandDepth="1" ShowCheckBoxes="All" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

The treeview uses a specific HTML structure that is going to be hard to change...  But you could look to using CSS to adjust the location of the checkboxes, or use an alternative control (repeater bound to a datasource that has an index parameter indicating how many spaces to indent, but this would not have the expand collapse functionality).